# Matlab k-means cosine assigns everything to one cluster

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, normalization, k-means

I'm using Matlab's regular kmeans algorithm with 'Distance','cosine','EmptyAction','drop' on an L2-normalized feature matrix and I have a problem. The output that Matlab generates is simply assigning EVERY datapoint to cluster `1.00000`, even if k=20, and all centroids in C are `NaN`. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

The layout of the matrix is ([0,1,...,1,0,1],[...],[0,1,...,1,0,1]). I've done the L2-normalization using Python's `numpy.linalg.norm` before I passed the file to Matlab. This is the exact way I am running kmeans:

```
m=importdata('matrix.txt');
data=m'; % transpose, because kmeans treats columns as features instead of rows
[L, C]=kmeans(data, 20, 'Distance', 'cosine', 'EmptyAction', 'drop')
```

Here is a sample of my normalized dataset:

```
10.3440804328
12.6885775404
15.5884572681
15.9059737206
17.4355957742
17.0
17.3493515729
17.3205080757
18.6279360102
19.7230829233
21.400934559
22.0
22.5831795813
23.0
24.0416305603
25.2388589282
26.8141753556
22.5388553392
9.2736184955
13.5277492585
15.2970585408
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information let me know!

Comment: from what I understood of the example they show in the doc, the kmeans works with sets of x-y coordinates, while you only supply one feature per row, do you have any associated value with your data you should include ?

Comment: I was assuming that in this case, he only had one feature

Comment: maybe add a second column of 1s ?

Comment: That would definitely make it do something, depends on what this means "One minus the cosine of the included angle between points (treated as vectors). Each centroid is the mean of the points in that cluster, after normalizing those points to unit Euclidean length."

Comment: See my reply to Matt's answer. Spherical k-means (or the mathematical descriptions I could find) takes a unit vector as input. Is it possible that this would be different for Matlab's implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the cosine distance that is making it fail, it works with sqEuclidean.  I think the cosine distance needs more info, or else doesn't make sense on your data set.

Edit:  I will agree with you that the documentation is a little vague here...but the definition of cosine distance in the pdist function of Matlab is: "One minus the cosine of the included angle between points (treated as vectors)."

I take it from that, that the angle must be included(I am assuming in the next column).  But that kind of seems like it defeats the purpose.[cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)
Edit again:  I guess it is more likely that included means "the included angle between 2 vectors".  In this case I think cosine expects 2 or more columns to work on.

Also, if your already into python there are some good machine learning tools there as well.  Here is [one I have used](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/).  There is also [MILK](http://packages.python.org/milk/index.html), but I have never used it myself.

Comment: As far as I know, kmeans with cosine takes a unit vector as input, doesn't it? E.g., see this description for "spherical k-means", as it is also known: http://www.shi-zhong.com/papers/oskm_ijcnn05.pdf
Any more ideas?

Comment: Also, although sklearn has kmeans, it doesn't allow me to set a different distance measure, or does it? It's only Euclidean AFAICT.

Comment: You can see by running pdist(data,'cosine') that it is calculating a distance of zero for all of your data.  So clearly Matlab's definition is not what you are expecting.  If you put a column of ones next to your data, you do get something, but I'm not very familiar with cosine distance so I don't know what to expect.

Comment: You were right, I was giving it the wrong input data. For the normalization I should have done: def l2(a):
    powered=np.power(a,2)
    norm=np.matrix(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(a,2),1)))
    return a/np.tile(norm,a.shape[1])